# I have a "bad token" error can anybody tell me why? (codehs)

Tags: python

```
Ideal= int(input("What grade do you want on your next assignment?"))

Current= int(input("What is your current grade in the class?"))
weight = int (input("What is the weight of the assignment (how much of your grade is it worth)?"))
print Ideal

print Current

print weight

Final_grade = Ideal − (( 1 − weight ) * Current)* weight

print "You will need to get a" , Final_grade , "on your next assignment to recieve a" , Current , "in this class"
```

Comment: Please give more detail of the error you're getting, and also it might help to specify what version of Python you are using.

Comment: Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: ParseError: bad token on line 10; im using a python module called "codehs" and im running on normal python, not python 3

Comment: @Wondercricket  Thank you, yours worked! I copy and pasted this from the web, so thats probably why.

Comment: Your code has a unicode hyphen `−`. Try replacing it with a standard hyphen `-`

Comment: Python 3 is normal today. Which version number do you use? Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: That's a good question. The `print` statements would have to be Python 2, while the `int(input(...))` expressions look like Python 3.

Comment: @FredLarson The `int(input(...))` could work in 2.x as well but would be very bad style of course.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your `−` character is not actually minus character. You might have copied this piece of code from somewhere which didn't actually have the minus character.

This is the correct minus character : `-`

Try this:

```
Ideal= int(input("What grade do you want on your next assignment?"))

Current= int(input("What is your current grade in the class?"))
weight = int (input("What is the weight of the assignment (how much of your grade is it worth)?"))
print Ideal

print Current

print weight

Final_grade = Ideal - (( 1 - weight ) * Current)* weight

print "You will need to get a" , Final_grade , "on your next assignment to recieve a" , Current , "in this class"
```

Output:

```
What grade do you want on your next assignment?5
What is your current grade in the class?4
What is the weight of the assignment (how much of your grade is it worth)?4
5
4
4
You will need to get a 53 on your next assignment to recieve a 4 in this class
```